# assembly x86 floating point operations

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86

i am trying to understand how these operations work ...

for example if i have a stack with values

```
5.0 , 2.0 , 3.0 , 8.0
ST0 , ST1 , ST2 , ST3
```

what are the results of these operations ?

1, fadd 
2, fmul
3, fst ST1

i find out that fadd and fmul takes the ST0 and ST1 and execute the operation ... so the results are

```
1, 7.0 , 3.0 , 8.0 
2, 10.0 , 3.0 , 8.0
```

am i right ? :)

also i have no idea what is "fst" doing and how it works ... so if someone can explain it for me on this example it would be very helpful ...

thank you very much

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-5477/eoizy.html

http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_117.html

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [intel instruction set reference](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf) to understand what each instruction does. In addition I recommend [Simply FPU](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm) because it's an awesome tutorial.

Also, you could just run the thing in a debugger and see what's happening for yourself:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a no-argument `fadd` or no-argument `fmul`.

`fst ST1` copies `ST0` to `ST1`.

Comment: first , thank you very much for your response :)
so the result of fst ST1 for these example is 

5.0 , 5.0 , 3.0 , 8.0  ? :)